# how to install rmagick on ubuntu 8

Tags: installation, imagemagick, gem, rmagick

I am trying to install the rmagick gem in ubuntu, but is is failing. the output of gem_make.out is at:
http://pastie.org/private/m7gyn96xy6yqmtp2kyog

the output of mkmf.log is at http://pastie.org/private/viagrieyiz9pxt6noyg4q . please help in installing rmagick! i need to learn which library to install so that the function InitializeMagick() is found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the dev files for **magickcore, magick++, and magickwand:**

You can install them using apt-get like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```